Request Elevation From Python Script Via Windows Terminal
Adapted from Request UAC elevation,
I created a Python file getelev.py and put it in PYTHONPATH, so it can be called with command import getelev.
import ctypes, sys, os

shell = ctypes.windll.shell32
iswt  = os.system('where.exe wt.exe >Nul 2>&1') == 0

if shell.IsUserAnAdmin() == 0:
    if iswt:
        shell.ShellExecuteW(None, "runas", "wt.exe", " ".join(sys.argv), None, 1)
    else:
        shell.ShellExecuteW(None, "runas", sys.executable, " ".join(sys.argv), None, 1)
    sys.exit()

The script works fine. But I need to improve on the part if iswt:, because I get an error message:
[error 2147942593 (0x800700c1) when launching `D:\#DATA\#BATCH\#PYTHONPATH\test.py']

The script was not fully successful when opened in Windows Terminal.
I need same as vbscript command:
Set UAC=CreateObject("Shell.Application")
UAC.ShellExecute "wt.exe", "-p Python py.exe ""D:\#DATA\#BATCH\#PYTHONPATH\test2.py""", "", "runas", 1

Which part is wrong, I also tried:
script_path = r"D:\#DATA\#BATCH\#PYTHONPATH\test2.py"
command = f'wt.exe -p Python py.exe "{script_path}"'
ctypes.windll.shell32.ShellExecuteW(None, "runas", command, None, None, 1)

Thank You.

What's the deal with wt.exe? Why involving it? Looks like an useless extra burden to me.
